# BDE / ODBC with SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sql-server-2014, bde

I was trying to use BDE connected to SQL Server 2014 database.

It's connected and select works fine, but when I try to update some table, some values used in one column goes to another.

What changed? and what can I do to work like previous versions of SQL (2012 works fine)?

Plus, the same happen with odbc using old dll (2005 version).

Comment: You've not provided anything like enough information for anyone to help you here.

Comment: That's all information I have too. I'm trying to use a great ERP that's using bde. In some screens, when user try update some informations, values goes to wrong column.